# Trying to copy using Sudo user

Tags: shell, sudo, cat, chown

I have a "SuperUser" which has write permissions to /opt/example folder. I have a regular user named "user" which has read permissions to /opt and "user" has a directory /home/user/example. "user" has sudo permissions. I want to copy entire example folder from "/home/user/example" to "/opt/example". I have tried below options from the existing threads, but none of them worked.

[copy file from user to another in linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/278184/copy-file-from-user-to-another-in-linux)

```
ssh SuperUser@xx.xx.xx.x 'sudo tar -C /home/example/ -czf - .' | tar -C /opt/example/ -xzf -

scp -r /home/example /opt/example/

sudo chown SuperUser /home/example

sudo -u SuperUser < /home/example sh -c 'cat > /opt/example' 

cat ~/home/example | sudo -u SuperUser tee ~/opt/example >/dev/null
```

I believe i am missing something here.Could any one correct me??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The root account will retain ownerships on filles when it copies, and it can also read all files and write to your target directory

```
sudo cp -a /home/user/example /opt/
```

If the target `/opt/example` already exists you can use this

```
sudo cp -a /home/user/example/. /opt/example/
```

Your own ottempts weren't quite right because...

- `ssh` is for connecting to a remote machine
- `scp` is for copying to/from a remote machine
- `sudo chown` changed the ownership of the target directory but didn't copy anything
- `sudo ... cat` I'm not sure what was going on here
- `cat | sudo` likewise

Comment: Thank you for the clear explanation.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that you try

```
sudo cp -p -R /home/user/example /opt/example
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/351984)

Comment: Thank you. It worked

Comment: @AdminBee it does provide an answer. Or was it the "Have you tried...?" that you were objecting to?

Comment: @roaima Yes, it sounded like a request for clarification, in particular since it is lacking any explanation on why the answerer thinks this solves the OPs problem or how they concluded what actually caused the OPs problem.